# JavaScript: How to assign a default value if none of the radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript

In an HTML form, a radio button named color may or may not exist. I'd like to check if this radio button doesn't exist or if it exists none of the radio buttons is selected and if so, assign a default value:

```
if (document.getElementsByName("color") === undefined){
      color= "red";
   }else{
      color = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked').value;
}
```

But the code always goes to the 'else' whether a radio button exist or not, is selected or not, and then complains "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the HTML which contains the input elements with the name color.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByName("color")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) will never returns `undefined` but an empty [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to mix `getElementsByName` with `querySelector`:

**Snippet when checkbox exists**

```js
var color = 'red';
var check = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked');
if (check) color = check.value;

console.log(color);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Hello!" checked>
```

**Snippet when checkbox doesn't exist**

```js
var color = 'red';
var check = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked');
if (check) color = check.value;

console.log(color);
```

**Snippet when dropdown exist**

```js
var color = 'red';
var selected = document.querySelector('select[name="color"] option:checked');
if (selected) color = selected.value;

console.log(color);
```

```html
<select name="color">
  <option value='one'>One<option>
  <option selected value='two'>Two<option>
</select>
```

## Resource

- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

  > Returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first matching element

Comment: BTW, what's the equivalent of document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked') for a pulldown menu? Thanks!

Comment: @user4444173 did you mean dropdown? (Select)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns an array and a blank one if no records

```
if (document.getElementsByName("color").length == 0){
    color= "red";
} else {
    color = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` function returns a `NodeList` element, even if it's empty!

You can check **length** of result `if (document.getElementbyName('color').length === 0)`

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7m439tcu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using querySelector with `:checked`, then it only selects checked checkboxes with the name "color". If no checkboxes are checked, then it will return `null`. And because `null` has no key `value`, you get an error. Try

```
if (document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked') === null){
  color= "red";
}else{
  color = document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers, DOM queries are expensive! So try and re-use one query rather than wasting time executing two redundant queries:

```
var color = (
  document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked') || { value: 'red' }
).value;
```

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will return `null` if no such element exists, so the `||` operator will either short-circuit if there is an element, or return `{ value: 'red' }` if there isn't, then access the `value` property of whichever object is chosen.